# How to parse the Bibliography in elegant way on EnsiWiki

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api, bibliography, wikimedia

I'm using this [website](https://ensiwiki.ensimag.fr) which is powered by [MediaWiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki), my problem is that I'm trying to reference the bibliography in elegant way following the procedure explained in the [Help:Footnotes](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Footnotes), but the references rendering isn't working at all.

[image: Result]

can you please tell me how to render my bibliography in elegant way?

```
{{#tag:ref|...{{tc}}...{{{1}}}...}}

{|class=wikitable
|
:The only reference to Excel For Dummies.<ref>Excel For Dummies, First Edition, Hungry Minds, Inc., 1980.</ref>

:The first reference to Perry's Handbook.<ref name="Perry">Perry's  Handbook, Sixth Edition, McGraw-Hill Co., 1984.</ref> 

:The second reference to Perry's Handbook.<ref name="Perry"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

:The third reference to Perry's Handbook.<ref name="Perry"/>

|}

{|class=wikitable
|
<references/>
|}
```

also tried:

```
<ref>{{cite book
|author1-last=Clément
|author1-first= Serge
|author2-last=Rolland
|author2-first=Christine
|author3-last=Thoer-Fabre
|author3-first=Christine
|title=Usages, normes, autonomie : analyse critique de la bibliographie concernant le vieillissement de la population
|url=https://halshs.archives-ouvertes.fr/halshs-00142514
|year=2007
|publisher=PARIS: Plan Urbanisme Construction Architecture
|isbn=2-11-085689-0
|page=240 }}</ref>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to activate the extension [Cite](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Cite), which is bundled with *MediaWiki* in `LocalSettings.php`:

```php
wfLoadExtension( 'Cite' );
```

Comment: I'm editing the page on the browser, tried to add that line to the end of my page, but it didn't work!

Comment: And *Cite* is not installed there: https://ensiwiki.ensimag.fr/index.php?title=Sp%C3%A9cial:Version. If you don't have access to its server, try contacting that wiki's admin.